# How to make tab not scrollable in TabLayout when I click from one tab to another

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, superclass

I successfully stopped scroll in ViewPager when you swipe from one tab fragment to another in ViewPager now I can't figure out how to do the same for Tab Bar.  Currently if you click between one tab to another, the tabs scroll from tab to tab. I want to make it stop scroll and work more like in Facebook Messenger when you click between tabs.

I created a CustomViewPager to stop ViewPager tab scroll:

[image]

in XML file I have:

```
    <com.example.myname.tabbar.CustomViewPager/>
```

I tried to create several different superclasses for CustomTabBar but nothing works. I used ViewPager, TabLayout.tab, PagerTabStrip, ViewPager, ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener, CustomViewPager and none of these work. I've tried various code I've looked up on StackOverflow and nothing works.

How to disable scroll between fragments when tab fragment is clicked on in TabLayout?

Comment: Did you found a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, I found a solution that works for me. Maybe it'll work for you too.  I answered my own question, look there and try it.

Answer (score 2):

To make the TabLayout non scrollable do the following:

In code: 
myTabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
I think the above i.e. setting it programmatically suits you.

In XML
app:tabMode="fixed"

Hope this helps you.

Comment: you should also add app namespace as follows: xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com.apk.res-auto"

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this issue that works for me. It stopped the scroll effect when clicking between different tabs in tabLayout.

I added the following code in my CustomViewPager.java:

```
@Override
public void setCurrentItem(int item, boolean smoothScroll) {
    super.setCurrentItem(item, false);
}

@Override
public void setCurrentItem(int item) {


    super.setCurrentItem(item, false);

}
```